# One of the URLs on my web site (on Azure VM Windows 2012 server) has started getting “This page can't be displayed” when browsed on my , .NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, azure, iis

One of the URL's to my website no longer works and gives me this error: "This page can't be displayed. Make sure the web address http://my_web's_previous_IP is correct"

(This is strange because "my_web's_previous_IP" was my web's IP up until January, when  IP was changed after I restarted Azure .)

I have 4 different URL's registered to reach web. All 4 used to work ok, but now one, the primary one, doesn't anymore.
1. my_long_URL.org FAILS (and this is the primary web URL on my Azure IIS) 
2. www.my_long_URL.org FAILS
3. my_long_URL.com works tiny_URL.org works
4. tiny_URL.com works www..org & com works

Web is VB.NET web app on Azure VM Windows 2012 server.

Registrar for my_long_URL.org says it's generating correct IP ok.
All email to my web by name@my_long_URL.org works ok and gets to my Azure email processing app ok.

I've done obvious things like restart the VM.

Azure > Windows > IIS Manager > Connections > Start Page > () > Application Pools > Sites > my_long_URL.org > each Site Binding is type http, port 80, and has same Azure internal IP Address.

... > Site Bindings > command to Browse: browses web for all ok, except I get the error browsing: www.my_long_URL.org

Site Bindings > command to Browse: my_long_URL.org WORKS OK(!)

I get exact same browse outcome when I click Actions column on the right-hand side > the URL's below Actions > Browse Website.

I have tried removing and re-adding bindings for both www.my_long_URL.org and my_long_URL.org but still get problem.

Azure > Windows > IIS Manager > Connections > Start Page > () > Application Pools > Sites > my_long_URL.org > right click it > Manage Web.. > Browse: works ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few weeks, it just started working again!
Explanation:
A. I prayed to God, so maybe it was a miracle.  :-)
B. The bad URL was the only one hosted by Aabaco.  The other URLs were hosted by Network Solutions.  The www error message always showed the old IP from back in January.  However, the URL worked with email.  So maybe Aabaco had a fault using the new IP with http traffic.

But, it works now!  Praise God!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have created a test VM and host a web site on it. It works well.

I guess you may not set the right Network security group inbound security rules.

So you will face this error.

[image]

So I suggest you could follow below steps to check you have already add the new  Network security group inbound security rules.

1. Select networking in the VM

[image]

2.Click add the inbound port role.

[image]

3.Add your IIS website port in it.

Then it will work well. More details about how to host web site in IIS, you could refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qqTS2oBHDw).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Brando, but that was not it.